# Wordpress infinite post cycle

Tags: posts, loop

What I need is one post (feature image+content text) per page. When you click on a fullscreen div (class=next)on top of everything, then next post loads per page. When the oldest and last post appears, clicking on its feature image loads the first post again (latest post added by date). 
One post per page. 
Infinite cycle of posts by adding date, starting with the latest post added.

Below is the code with two problems to solve.

1. Oldest post does not cycle back to the first post, to create an infinite cycle of posts.
2. The index (latest post )loads all content from all posts, all the next posts are fine, containing only their content.

   ```
   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_adjacent_post( false, '', true ) ); ?>">
   <span class="next"></span>
   <div class="featured-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>')"></div></a>
   <div class="content">
   <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date' ) ); while($query->have_posts()){ $query->the_post(); } ?>
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><?php the_content(); ?>
   <?php endwhile; else: ?>
   <?php _e(''); ?><?php endif; ?>
   </div>
   ```

Need help! Thanks!

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be more simple. Like this:

```
<?php
$next_post = get_previous_post();
if( empty( $next_post ) ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
    $next_post = $posts[0];
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>">
    <span class="next"></span>
    <div class="featured-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $next_post->ID ) ); ?>')"></div>
</a>
<div class="content">
    <?php
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $next_post->ID ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sohan.

I get error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

for this line:

            $posts = get_post( 'posts_per_page' => 1 );


I tried '1' but no help.

S

Comment: My bad.. Just fixed the code. Please use the latest edit.

Comment: Much better, but still the cycle is not complete. It will not connect the oldest and newest post to create an infinite cycle of posts. The linking order is also oldest to newest, I need newest to oldest and then back to the newest post.

S

Comment: In that case you just have to replace `get_next_post();` with `get_previous_post();`. I'll edit that for you.

Comment: Thank You so much Sohan! That makes a perfect post loop, but it starts with the second latest post. How can I make it start with the latest post added, not the second to the latest (by date)?

Comment: When you are already on a post, then it should link to the next post which is second latest post.. Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: When I enter the index catalogue URL of the index.php file in browser, then the second latest post appears, not the very latest by date. When I add a new post in WP admin, then again second latest appears but not the one I just added. The one I just added appears in the cycle as the last post. Hopefully it makes sense. Thanks!